# Firebase Push Notification TokenRefresh - Best Practices to ensure proper token is updated

Tags: firebase, xamarin

I am working to implement push notifications for Android & iOS. Using the Firebase Cloud Messaging service and the Plugin.FirebasePushnotification by Rendy Del Rossaio nuget package.  I have a working prototype with a backend service (Firebase Admin) pushing the notifications. However the one process that I’m struggling with is updating the DeviceID (Token) and pairing it with a unique identifier for the device. We are pushing notifications to specific devices pairing the FCM DeviceID  and the application’s UserID. If there were a guarantee that a user would only be associated with a single device, then we would not have a problem. However, users can be associated with multiple devices (Phone or tablet). So when Firebase chooses to update the DeviceID how do we ensure that the proper DeviceID is being updated. Since both Hardware manufacturers don't reveal a serial number or MAC it is incumbent on the developer to do this. An option that I’m contemplating is to generate my own ID (GUID) and store it external from the app, but that has risks also. So I’m looking for a Best Practices solution to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You need to keep track of, per user, the full list of devices (and their tokens) they are using. Firebase won't do that for you - it just keeps track of individual devices without respect to the person who might be using it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am keenly aware that I have to keep track of that information, thus the nature of my question. If I have a UserID associated with 2 different devices (e.g. an Android phone and an Android tablet) how does one distinguish between the 2. In my app, on a Token Refresh I run a method to send that token to my DB associated with the UID and the OS. But when I look for a record to update I would like a key to distinguish each device from the other. Ideally that key would persist on the device   and I would also save it to my DB. So looking for a Best Practices solution.

Comment: It sounds like you actually have two simple questions here that have little to do with FCM on their own terms: 1) How do I uniquely identify an Android device.  2) How do I uniquely identify an iOS device.  I've marked this question as a duplicate on those two points since there isn't anything to change for FCM.  If your question is more than just about finding unique device IDs, I suggest posting separately with that specific issue in mind.

Comment: @DougStevenson the posts you reference I had already read in my research. They are 12 & 13 years old and they are completely different than the nature of my question. My question is is seeking a best practices solution to identify a way to uniquely identify a device because there is no hardware identifier, exactly as those 3 posts point out. I suspect that I am not the only one who has faced this situation and i also suspect someone has a solution.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow get updated with new answers and information as they become available - what you see there represents all of the available information.  Sorry if this is bad news to you, but there is nothing more to add (and SO doesn't allow for duplicate questions). The lack of a consistent hardware based device ID is probably a security feature to prevent apps from collecting data that uniquely ID someone, which I'm sure you can agree is a privacy problem.